# Group the two rows but Last 2 columns value is different

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have the below table in which I got the data from different tables.

| Policy_Number | Name_Of_Client | Email | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BEI/BGAMMQ/0000431 | Test, Lda | t@t.com | NULL |
| BEI/BGAMMQ/0000431 | Test, Lda | NULL | 1212121212 |

Can someone please help me to get the result as below?

| Policy_Number | Name_Of_Client | Email | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BEI/BGAMMQ/0000431 | Test, Lda | t@t.com | 1212121212 |

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate by policy number and name of client, then select the max of the email and phone.

```sql
SELECT Policy_Number, Name_Of_Client, MAX(Email) AS Email, MAX(Phone) AS Phone
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Policy_Number, Name_Of_Client;
```

By the way, your table in its current state might imply that there is some sort of design or data gathering problem.  The output you want is the version you probably should be using.